# XMLHttpRequest does not send file

Tags: javascript, php, xmlhttprequest

I want to upload a file trough a XMLHttpRequest. i have looked everywhere for examples and found quite a few. But i cant figer out what it is i am doing wrong. This is my code. The function is triggerd when a button is pressed. It not wrapped in from tags

```
function upl_kost() {
var url = "proces_data.php?ref=upload_kost";
var hr;
var file = document.getElementById("file_kost");
var formData = new FormData();

formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);

if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    hr=new XMLHttpRequest();
  } else {
    hr=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
hr.open("POST", url, true);

hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");

hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
   if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
        var return_data = hr.responseText;
        alert(return_data);
    }
}
hr.send(formData);
}
```

and this function catches it.

```
if($_GET['ref'] == 'upload_kost') {
var_dump($_FILES);
}
```

My problem is that the $_FILES stays empty. When i look at the file.files variable in the js its loaded with the data from the file that i am trying to upload.

Thanks!

Comment: Files (uploading) requires a POST method, not GET. So, if your form's method is set to GET, change it to POST. You could also use `$_REQUEST` instead of `$_GET` which can be used for both POST and GET. Try `if($_REQUEST['ref'] == 'upload_kost')`

Comment: @Fred-ii- `ref=upload_kost` is in `url`, i.e. it's a _GET_ parameter. the _XMLHttpRequest_ is opened as a _POST_, and then `formData` is sent as post data.

Comment: I think thats not the problem. as you can see by the hr.open("POST", url, true); it is set to post. The vardump is triggerd but its just empty

Comment: Then, how is `upl_kost()` being called, or is it not being called at all?

Comment: <input type="file" id="file_kost" name="file_kost" />
  <button type="submit" id="upload-button" onclick="upl_kost()">Upload</button> @Fred-ii-

Comment: I'd need to see more code, your full HTML form and PHP handler. I can't tell what's not making it work (not from what you've posted), unless somebody knows more about it than I do with what you posted for code.

Comment: Which browse are you using? FormData is only supported in IE 10+

Comment: This is al the code. As i stated above its nor wrapped in from tags. This is all the code there is to it. When i check the file.files variable in the js then its filled with the correct uploaded data but it doesnt parse it to the php script

Comment: @asmodeus i am using firfox

Comment: Is this code correct then ? 

formData.append("upload", file.files[0]);

Try chaning to:

formData.append("upload", file);

Comment: @asmodeus No diddent work

Comment: You say that's your entire code. How is the "upload" part supposed to work? Uploading requires `move_uploaded_file()` - Plus, I see no form, so I can't help you, because I don't know what you're trying to achieve with what you have posted.

Comment: I cant upload the file if the data of the file is not passed to the script. Thats the part that wassent working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reduce your *JavaScript* down to minimum required for this, then add in some helpful messages you can look in your console for

```
function upl_kost() {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest(),
        url = 'proces_data.php?ref=upload_kost',
        fd = new FormData(),
        elm = document.getElementById('file_kost');

    // debug <input>
    if (!elm)
        console.warn('Element not found');
    else if (!(elm instanceof HTMLInputElement))
        console.warn('Element not an <input>');
    else if (!elm.files || elm.files.length === 0)
        console.warn('<input> has no files');
    else
        console.info('<input> looks okay');
    // end debug <input>

    fd.append('upload', elm.files[0]);

    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        console.log('Response:', this.responseText);
    });

    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.send(fd);
}
```

If you're still having a problem, it may be server-side, e.g. are you performing a redirect before trying to access `$_FILES`?

Comment: Oke I tried this and it says input look okay. I'm not performing any redirecting. proces_data.php is a page where i catch all my xmlhttprequests. The code in my post is al there is to it.

Comment: The final client side check you can do is look at the network tab / enable console logging of xmlhttprequest and look from the console to see if the sent data does indeed include the file (which I'm 99% sure it does), then you know for sure that the problem is server-side. Try doing a `var_dump` that isn't in any `if`s/functions/etc, e.g. test using a new _php_ page which only has the `var_dump`.

Comment: When i use this code and i look at the xhr.responseText; its works. I have no idee why its works with this code and not with mine but it does

Comment: Even i am trying same thing but it shows all data about file in console log but when i send this data using xhr to my upload.php file to catch the data by using var_dump($_FILES) it shows empty array in networks tab

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you're setting the content type of the request

```
hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "multipart/form-data");
```

If you ever saw a multipart/formdata post you'll notice the content type header has a boundary

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----webko2354645675756
```

which is missing from your code.
If you do not set the content type header the browser will correctly set it and the required boundary. This will allow the server to properly parse the request body.